# Worklight console is not opening

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I use Java 7 and when I try to start worklight console from Eclipse I get server errors. 
In browser I get the message "Server error. Contact the server administrator." in IBM MobileFirst Platform Operations Console. 
Application's preview is not accessible also.

This is my logs from console:

`[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightConsole started in 9.391 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightAnalytics started in 9.917 seconds.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.createContextLoader(ContextLoaderListener.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:44)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2227)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load 'ContextLoader.properties': class path resource [ContextLoader.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    ... 6 more
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.Messages.getResourceString(Messages.java:208)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.Messages.get(Messages.java:230)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.Messages.getString(Messages.java:254)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.GeneralUtil.getProductBuildVersion(GeneralUtil.java:50)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.listeners.WorklightManagementServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WorklightManagementServletContextListener.java:41)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2227)
    at [internal classes]
[ERROR   ] M:\IBM\From_Sergey\Mobilefirst%20eclipse\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_94.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
M:\IBM\From_Sergey\Mobilefirst%20eclipse\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_94.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] M:\IBM\From_Sergey\Mobilefirst%20eclipse\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_94.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
M:\IBM\From_Sergey\Mobilefirst%20eclipse\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_94.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet                                                                                                                ManagementServlet                                                                                                               WorklightServices                                                                                                               java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.initAlternateShortcutMap(DeploymentConfiguration.java:386)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.init(DeploymentConfiguration.java:167)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.getDeploymentConfiguration(RestServlet.java:202)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.createRequestProcessor(RestServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.wink.common.internal.i18n.resource, locale en_US
    ... 14 more
[ERROR   ] SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:395)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.initAlternateShortcutMap(DeploymentConfiguration.java:386)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.init(DeploymentConfiguration.java:167)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.getDeploymentConfiguration(RestServlet.java:202)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.createRequestProcessor(RestServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.wink.common.internal.i18n.resource, locale en_US
    ... 14 more`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using Java 8.
Worklight/MobileFirst Platform does not support Java 8 at this time.

Please downgrade to Java 6 or 7 and try again.

Comment: I try to use Java 7 but it doesn't help. I still see the message "Server error. Contact the server administrator." in IBM MobileFirst Platform Operations Console.

Comment: @vasyok, Also, are the errors different after downgrading? Can you update the question with fresh logs?

Comment: Thanks, I created a new project in fresh workspace but it also didn't help. Also I updated my question with current logs.

Comment: Can you try in a path without spaces? "M:\IBM\From_Sergey\Mobilefirst%20eclipse\" - change "Mobilefirst eclipse" to "Mobilefirst_eclipse"